# How to mock joins in queryDsl (jpa + mockito)?

Tags: java, jpa, mocking, mockito, querydsl

Given the queryDsl code that selects from entities by joining them

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BlahRepository {

  private final JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory;

  public List<YyzPerEntity> getYyzPerById(Long id) {

    final QYyzPerEntity n = YyzPerEntity;
    final QDufEntity d = dufEntity;
    final QWofEntity g = wofEntity;

    return jpaQueryFactory
      .selectFrom(n)
      .leftJoin(d)
      .on(n.pLnr.eq(d.dufEntityPK.dofx))
      .leftJoin(g)
      .on(d.wof.getID().eq(g.Id))
      .where(g.Id.eq(Id))
      .fetch();
  }
```

I want to mock the join part like:

```
@Mock private JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
private JPAQuery queryMock;
@InjectMocks private BlahRepository blahRepository;

@Test
  void byId() {
    // arrange
    queryMock = mock(JPAQuery.class);
  when(queryFactory.selectFrom(QYyzPerEntity.yzPerEntity))
  .thenReturn(queryMock);
 // how to mock joins here... ? 
  when(queryMock.fetch()).thenReturn(List.of(QYyzPerEntity.yzPerEntity));

  // act
  List<YyzPerEntity> yyzPerById =
  blahRepository.getYyzPerById(123L);

  // assert
  assertThat(yyzPerById).isNotNull();
```

any ideas what I could try?

Error that I get is:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.on(...) because the return value of com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.leftJoin(com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath) is null
```

Is it possible at all or cannot be mocked ?

Comment: Why would you mock `JPAQuery`? At this point you're either testing the internals of Querydsl, or making sure that you wrote what you wrote. Just mock the entire `blahRepository` instead. And if you want to test `blahRepository` properly, its best to do so in an integration test that actually executes the query against a database. There is also the possibility to execute the query against mock data using `querydsl-collections`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to mock builder API's, like for example `JPAQuery`, is to use `Answers.RETURNS_SELF` as default stub.

For example, use the following to instantiate your `queryMock`:

```java
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SELF) JPAQuery queryMock;
```